# How to add new rows in existing dataframe based on the column values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe, but I want to add new rows based on existing dataframe. Each ID has its own group in which it inherits from its parent. But I want to append new rows to the dataframe where it would make the parent id into the new id and add a group that is based on its child

For example:

```
ID    |    Parent    | Group
1001  |    2345      |  1
2001  |    3456      |  1
2002  |    3456      |  1
2003  |    3456      |  1
3001  |    4567      |  2
3002  |    4567      |  2
4012  |    5678      |  3
5123  |    6789      |  3
```

The expected result:

```
ID    |    Parent    | Group
1001  |    2345      |  1
2001  |    3456      |  1
2002  |    3456      |  1
2003  |    3456      |  1
3001  |    4567      |  2
3002  |    4567      |  2
4012  |    5678      |  3
5123  |    6789      |  3
2345  |    2345      |  1
3456  |    3456      |  1
4567  |    4567      |  2
5678  |    5678      |  3
6789  |    6789      |  3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) for overwrite column `ID` by `Parent` and [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) for remove duplicates by specified columns in list:

```
df1 = df.assign(ID = df['Parent']).drop_duplicates(['Parent','Group'])
df2 = pd.concat([df, df1], ignore_index=True)
print (df2)

      ID  Parent  Group
0   1001    2345      1
1   2001    3456      1
2   2002    3456      1
3   2003    3456      1
4   3001    4567      2
5   3002    4567      2
6   4012    5678      3
7   5123    6789      3
8   2345    2345      1
9   3456    3456      1
10  4567    4567      2
11  5678    5678      3
12  6789    6789      3
```

Comment: Hi thank you for answering, but I have multiple of the same parents in the columns so it appends multiple same times. is there a way to get only 1 instance of the parent column to add to the rows?

Comment: @Funky - hmm, can you modify your question data?

Comment: Sorry, I've modified it now :). so there are various IDs with the same Parents